# how to disable my website from being viewed on mobile devices?

Tags: mobile, joomla

Is there a script i can use to disable my entire website (in joomla) ,from being viewed on mobile devices? I haven't used any code yet. but I do use a script to disable right clicking but it's not for the mobile version. I don't want mobile viewing at all.

Comment: If someone really wanted to, they can spoof the mobile browser's User-Agent to make it appear as if they are using a desktop browser. There is no real way to disable mobile viewing, just like there is no real way to disable right clicking.

Comment: And while normally you see people asking help to make their sites mobile-friendly, this question is wanting to do the opposite. Why? Just pure curiosity

Comment: it's a blogsite just for personal use :) thank you.for your help and suggestions :)

Comment: That is not an answer. However I noticed the other comment you added. So is about blocking the download of images? You can't block the download of images. Try this: On a pc open chrome, open your site, press f12 to open the dev tools and click on the network tab. Refresh the page and you'll notice all the images are there ready to download. That is just one of the many ways to download the images (and any other file)

Comment: im speaking in a sense. of the average viewer...not advanced viewer.

Answer (score 1):

But of an odd one but you could do it using a CSS3 media query like so:

```
@media only screen (max-device-width : 768px) {
    html,body { display: none; } 
}
```

This will result in a completely blank screen for devices that are 768px and below. You would simply need to apply to above code to your template css file.

You could maybe also use Javascript like so:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    getElementById('body').style.display = 'none';
}
```

I haven't tested this on every mobile device out there but it will work on most

Comment: how do i disable opening the image up in a new window or saving it & where would i place the script for something like that?

Comment: I'm a little confused, I thought you wanted to completely disable your view from being viewed on a mobile device. If you require something else, please be very clear in your initial question